# Getting duplicate iOS notifications from IFTTT

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ipod-touch, notifications

I use IFTTT to send me iOS notifications for some of my recipes, but for some reason, every time it sends me a notification, it sends it twice. So every notification I get from IFTTT is duplicated.

Anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this. What I did was I deleted the iOS Notifications channel, then deleted the app from my iPhone, then re-installed the app, re-activated the channel, and re-created the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have more than one Apple device with IFTTT installed with reminder access turned on. When the app gets triggered both devices write to your reminder list. You can fix this by deleting IFTTT from either device.  Or, by not allowing one of the IFTTT apps on either device to access to reminders. Remember, one of them has to be able to write to your Reminders or the recipe won’t work. But just allow one.